# equation for double the total number of 5 items (trading game puzzle)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

**you have the following goods:**

$200$ apples

$350$ bananas

$200$ oranges

$600$ grapes

$400$ melons

Your goal is to receive back $400$ apples, $700$ bananas, $400$ oranges, $1200$ grapes, and $800$ melons in as few trades as possible.
(double each good class)

**rules/conditions:**

> 1. The market will trade you any good you want for any other. (you can trade apples for bananas, oranges, grapes, or melons)
> 2. You may trade your goods for half as much up to twice as much as what you offered. (ex. $20$ apples can be traded for $10-40$ bananas)
> 3. You trade your goods and once they are traded, they are gone (ex. you have $20$ apples you trade $10$ apples for $20$ bananas, you have $10$ more apples to trade with)
> 4. You don't receive anything back until all trading is completed
> 5. You can only trade whole numbers
>      (no trading half a banana)

/
show the equation needed to derive the amounts needed of what for what

Comment: MSE is not, generally speaking, a place where you present exercises for others to solve.  If this is a problem that you are trying to solve, please let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck.  If this is a puzzle that you are posing for others, the the [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) might be a better venue.

Comment: 10 trades is a trivial upper bound, and it's easily reduced to 8. 5 is a trivial lower bound. So you don't have a very big search space.